# After opening Ubuntu 16.04 cause error

Tags: boot, 16.04, unity, python

The screen is stuck on this black screen.

[image: oot]

Answer (score 0):

if that did not fix your problem you could take a USB put ubuntu on it (make sure this is a live session), install boot repair, and run boot repair on your system it should fix most boot problems.